# Eclipse Luna. Illegal position of bar with views

Tags: eclipse

Before I used Kepler version. This screenshots of [normal](https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2947/15303349309_037020f7d5_o.png) and [minimized](https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5611/15489901262_7df708a1ba_o.png) bar.

Now I decided change Kepler to last version: Luna SR1.
[Normal](https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2950/15303684577_a2409f7415_o.png) state bar seems as Kepler. But if I try minimize this bar, it [attach](https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3942/15467132806_4744f57db6_o.png) to right side of application.

But I want enable working version from Kepler. How I can this todo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move mouse cursor to the **----** marker on the fast view bar then mouse cursor changes to hand symbol then drag it where ever you want. I am using Eclipse Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) NOT SR1(I am on Ubuntu 14.04).

[image]

Comment: Hm, curious. Today again open Eclipse and yes - I see this marker "---". But yesterday marker was hidden and the panel was thinner.
Use SR1 and Windows8.